# SqlException when trying to access sharepoint site

Tags: 2010, sql, troubleshooting

I have a local sharepoint server 2010. I'm able to browse through the pages, go to the backend etc. But when it comes to the point that something needs to be written into the SQL-DB (e.g. upload a document and save it to a list) i get the following error:

```
[SqlException]: Login failed for user 'DNLG\AWA01$'.
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection  owniConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection  outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo  sqlPartitionInfo)
[HttpException]: Failed to login to session state SQL server for user    'NT-AUTORIT&#196;T\NETZWERKDIENST'.
[HttpException]: Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.
at  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection  conn, Exception e)
at  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo  sqlPartitionInfo)
at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling)
at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

How can I change the user DNLG\AWA01$? I dont know how sharepoint is thinking that it has to use this one, because i never heard of him. Or isn't that the problem here?

Best Regards,

LMW

**Edit:**
I can "solve" the problem when I restart my computer. Then the site is accessible until I do something which need access to the database.

**Edit2:**
I can access the backend using http://localhost/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx. The problem only occurs when I try to reach the front end sites

**Edit3:**
okay it seems that i have not access to the user DNLG\AWA01$ (the admin is not available)... does that mean that i have to re-install my sharepoint server? or can i enable anonymous access or something like that to get a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by "something needs to be written into the SQL-DB" - do you mean that you want to save something in SharePoint??

Comment: yes. sorry, i will improve that above

Comment: DNLG\AWA01$ must have been the system/service account that your administration have used while configuring your sharepoint environment... looks like it is a domain account, check with your administrator to make sure the password for this account is not expired or changed...

Comment: i have installed the sharepoint environment on my own, using DNLG\lmw. AWA01$ is the name of my computer, i will change the name and look if it affects the behaviour.

Comment: okay it seems that i have not access to the user DNLG\AWA01$ (the admin is not available)... does that mean that i have to re-install my sharepoint server? or can i enable anonymous access or something like that to get a workaround?

Comment: no, you just update the password if its expired or changed...

Comment: unfortunatley im not able to change/update the password, because the domain-admin is not available. that's why i try to find a way around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable SessionStateService...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607989.aspx